# How can a C# WinUI3 project be profiled when the lag is outside of the methods called?

Tags: c#, profiling, lag, winui-3

I have an issue where some code is taking a very long time to complete, so I tried to profile the CPU usage, and the area of the graph that contains the lag has absolutely no methods to display. In the whole session, the process' main method is the only method listed and takes up less than 25% of the time, so there is some kind of lag going on outside of the main method. My goal is to track down what is causing this lag.

I zoomed into the profiler and it looks like this method is stalling on something because it is the last method called before the long stall.

```
 ABI.Microsoft.UI.Xaml.IApplicationStaticsMethods.Start(WinRT.IObjectReference, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.ApplicationInitializationCallback)
```

Comment: Start is one of the first call, and all subsequent calls will be children or grand children so it's useless. We don't have enough information to help, please provide some reproducible code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: So it turns out that Microsoft's CPU tracer sucks? Or are there settings I can use to get an actual CPU trace?

Comment: No, read what I said. It just means Start is a top function that's never left unless the app exits, so every call will be included in Start. Seeing 80% in Start in a profiler is expected (and useless). You have to drill down in the calls

Comment: That's the problem, the children of start do not take up much of the total runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is waiting for something outside the main thread, probably I/O, of course the CPU time will be negligible. You need to profile on *wall-clock time, not CPU time,* and you need to look at all threads, to see which one is waiting for which. Look [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771).